# Vrm Heatsink recommendations

Tags: graphics-cards, heat-sink

So I've been looking for a cheap, quality solution to cool the VRM's on my XFX R9 270. Im trying to avoid bought heat-sinks for the fact that thermal pads can get pricey, and I'm weary of using thermal glue (for good reason, the card is coming up on 8 years old and still runs like a champ). I've been thinking of making some heat-sinks from thermally conductive aluminum tape (Ive tested the adhesive and it does not conduct electrical current at all) but I dont want to spend the time to make such if there is a solid, cheap alternative out there that I haven't seen or know about. Any recommendations or second opinions would be gladly appreciated ^.^

EDIT: Budget would be $30 for the heat-sinks, I'd need 8 to cover all the VRM's. Thermal pads/glue I know can vary widely in price so I'm open to ideas.

P.S. This is my first inquiry on SE so if what im asking is out of place or anything of the sort and such, I'll gladly ask in another forum ^.^ (Pretty sure I have the right place lol)

Comment: You will need to add a rough budget.